# Animation-play-state: running dosen't work in safari 11

Tags: jquery, css, html, safari, frontend

At first the element has property `animation-play-state: paused`, then the script modifies to property `animation-play-state: running`. All browsers deal with the task, but Safari 11 doesn't start the animation.

What's the problem? How can I solve this task?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state#Browser_compatibility) you'll need the `-webkit` prefix on the property for it to work in Safari

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with Safari.  Also, it appears that Safari does not require the -webkit- prefix anymore, so previous comment appears to be incorrect/outdated.

Comment: @calipoop did you figure out the cause or a fix?

Comment: @EricJohnson - I'll post my fix as an answer

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue:  my animation was paused initially and then set to "running" via JS.  This worked on all modern browsers except Safari.

My solution was to refactor/reverse the paused/running logic - I left the initial/default state as "running", not "paused".  Then I added and removed my "paused" class as necessary.  I'm no longer toggling the "running" state anywhere in my css, only a class with "paused" state.

The following setup now works for me in Safari:

```
.fancyEl {
  animation: fancyAni ease-in-out 1.5s infinite;
}

.fancyEl.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on calipoop's answer -- Safari 8 seemed to need the assigned animation to be changed entirely (in my example, I used 'fakename' to trick it).

Using the jquery line: `$(".animationpaused").removeClass("animationpaused");`

with CSS:

```
.snowgrid.snowgrid1 {
 -webkit-animation: snowgrid 9s 2 ease-in-out;
 animation: snowgrid 9s 2 ease-in-out;
}
.snowgrid.snowgrid2 {
 -webkit-animation: snowgrid 15s 1 ease-in-out;
 animation: snowgrid 15s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.snowgrid.animationpaused {
 -webkit-animation: fakename 10s 1 ease-in-out;
 animation: fakename 10s 1 ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
 animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
```

Most likely this will not allow you to toggle play/pause on the animation, but this works if you're simply waiting for a user interaction to start the animation.